# Using iText to read PDF file stored in image column

Tags: c#, itext

I have pdf files stored in an image column in a sql server database.  I want to read the contents of each file into something (string is what I am using, but open to suggestions) that I can use to search in `string.Contains("what I am looking for")`

I have the following code:

```
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select top 10 pdfData from Reports_Converted with (nolock)");
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (sdr.Read())
            {
                byte[] fileData = (byte[])sdr.GetValue(0);
                iTextPDF.PdfReader fileFromDpPdfReader = new iTextPDF.PdfReader(fileData);

                for (int page = 1; page <= fileFromDpPdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                {
                    IXmlTextParser.ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new IXmlTextParser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                    string currentText = IXmlTextParser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(fileFromDpPdfReader, page, strategy);

                    currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8,
                        Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));

                    pdfTextFromDatabase.Append(currentText);

                }

                finalTextResultFromDatabase = pdfTextFromDatabase.ToString();

            }
        }
```

As another point, I have similar code where I can read the file directly from a folder on my laptop.  Issue only comes into play when retrieving from database.

The error I see is `iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: 'PDF header signature not found.'` on this line of code:

```
iTextPDF.PdfReader fileFromDpPdfReader = new iTextPDF.PdfReader(fileData);
```

The answers I have found so far here on the stack deal with a physical file, not a scenario where the pdf is pulled from the database.

Comment: You probably won't be able to read a PDF into a string, since PDFs allow arbitrary binary contents and strings don't. Also PDFs don't necessarily store strings as a sequence of ASCII or Unicode chars.

Comment: @DourHighArch when I call this method on a local file, it converts it to a string I can search against.  `GetTextFromPage(fileFromDpPdfReader, page, strategy);`

Answer (score 1):

When pdf files are stored in Image column, which is SQL_LONGVARBINARY, the data format is already changed.
So when some one reads them back, there are good chances of failue, when validated for expected file format.

May be, a different way to handle this situation is, first create a temporary file of the required format, then read that temporary file.

```
byte[] fileData = (byte[])sdr.GetValue(0);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\temp.pdf", FileMode.Create);
fs.Write(fileData , 0, fileData.Length);
fs.Close();

iTextPDF.PdfReader fileFromDpPdfReader = new iTextPDF.PdfReader(@"C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\temp.pdf");
```

Comment: Good idea, I will give this a shot!

Comment: If you store the pdf in the file system add proposed here, can you check whether you can open it in a pdf viewer?